# Getting Crash randomly every where in view controller UI and maps

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps, calayer

I am geting crash when update ui in background

```
'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <CALayerArray: 0x172c50bf0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
```

Here is the my Code also getting random crashes and taking lots of memory whats i am doing wrong please suggest me.sorry for my english

```
[weakSelf performSelectorInBackground:@selector(googleMapView) withObject:nil];

googleMapView{
    [mapView animateToZoom:15];

    int k=0;
    @try {

        GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

        for(DRMapView * object in self.mapViewDataArray)
        {
            mMapViewObj=object;

            GMSMarker * markersLocal = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

            pinImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40+20*isiphone6Plus()+20*isiphone6(),60)];

            markersLocal.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mMapViewObj.mLatitude, mMapViewObj.mLongitude);
            [path addCoordinate:  markersLocal.position];


            view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40+20*isiphone6Plus()+20*isiphone6(),60)];
            view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
            pinImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            NSString * imageWithPercent;
            label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 12.5, 12.5)];
            if ([mMapViewObj.mGenderRatio isEqualToString:@""])
            {
                label.text =@"0";
                imageWithPercent =[NSString stringWithFormat:MAP_NO_ONE];
                pinImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageWithPercent];
            }
            else
            {
                //              NSString *genderRatio =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[DrinkrCommon valueOrNil:[[dict objectForKey:kGenderRatio] objectForKey:kMale]]];
                label.text =mMapViewObj.mTotalMembers;

                int percentage = [mMapViewObj.mMaleFemaleRatio intValue];

                if (percentage >= 80) {
                    imageWithPercent =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"map80"];
                    //NSLog(@"80====>>> %d",percentage);
                }
                else if (percentage >= 60) {
                    // NSLog(@"60====>>> %d",percentage);
                    imageWithPercent =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"map60"];
                }
                else if (percentage == 50) {
                    // NSLog(@"50====>>> %d",percentage);
                    imageWithPercent =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"map50"];
                }
                else if (percentage >= 40) {
                    // NSLog(@"40====>>> %d",percentage);
                    imageWithPercent =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"map40"];
                }
                else if (percentage >= 20) {
                    //  NSLog(@"20====>>> %d",percentage);
                    imageWithPercent =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"map20"];
                }
                else if (percentage <= 20) {
                    //  NSLog(@"<20====>>> %d",percentage);

                    imageWithPercent =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"map100"];

                }

                pinImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageWithPercent];
            }
            pinImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

            [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
            [label sizeToFit];
            label.layer.cornerRadius=label.frame.size.height / 2;
            label.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
            label.center=pinImageView.center;
            view.center=pinImageView.center;
            view.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            [view addSubview:pinImageView];
            [view addSubview:label];
            UIImage * markerIcon = [self imageFromView:view];

            markersLocal.userData=[NSNumber numberWithInt:k+1];
            markerView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:markerIcon];
            markerView.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            markersLocal.iconView = markerView;
            //    markers.map = mapView;
            marker=markersLocal;

            //        marker=m/MapViewObj.viewMarker;
            marker.map=mapView;
            k++;
        }

      GMSCoordinateBounds * bounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithPath:path];
      [mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:[GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:bounds withPadding:20.0f]];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
    }
    @finally {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see the exception is about a collection (in this case it's an array) is being modified while it is also being enumerated.

"Collection`CALayerArray`" means array of layers, (instances of UIView which are all backed up by layers) and modifications happen when you are calling `removeFromSuperview` or `addSubview`. The enumeration can happen anytime during redrawing.

So I think your problem could be in these 2 lines:

```
[view addSubview:pinImageView];
[view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Thanks for rpl @Eridana , i am getting every where  cash even table view

Comment: You are welcome. Try to review your code and figure out where is "view" could be in array. And second - all UI operations must be called in the main thread.

Comment: I have already review my code and i am using "view " only on this method.

Comment: try using an UncaughtException class library and see the crash to provide more details and debug if its something that is occurring due to UI and background work mixing together. Also enable the Exception breakpoint (not symbolic) and see where it stops . You can paste that image screenshot of stack trace.

Comment: Thanks @VickyDhas

Comment: Does that helps to your work or else ill pass another solution based on the code analysis. you can upvode the comment if its useful.